# (Google Maps API sign-up issue) Cannot register with debug key fingerprint

Tags: android, google-maps

> The fingerprint you entered is not valid. Please press the Back button
>   on your browser and enter a valid certificate fingerprint.

I am trying to register with my debug.keystore but google maps api site tells me its invalid.

Should I create a new one? What might be the problem? I tried 3 times, I am sure I am writing the SHA1 fingerprint right.

Comment: I generated a brand new key and I still have the same problem.

Comment: Sounds like you're not generating the fingerprint correctly, I've used maps with a debug keystore and it's definitely possible.

Comment: So I use code from actual google site:

     `keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore c:\Users\MyUser\.android\debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android`


I get this : 
    **10:94:44:96:86:E0:AB:27:BE:6B:77:D4:54:61:D1:A9:83:B6:58:A8**

Google maps api site says its invalid.

Comment: God... it is actually giving me sh1 instead of md5...

Comment: You should add this as an answer below and mark it as accepted then you can help out others with the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that jdk7 displays sha1 with keytool -list. I installed jdk6 v30 and it all worked with that keytool.

Answer (score 0):

I used the answer that Petrov suggests above. I had jdk1.7.0 installed so i went back to Oracle and downloaded "Java SE Development Kit 6u30".
Once i had jdk1.6.0_30 installed i again ran the "keytool" cmd from the cmd prompt and the key was accepted by Google. Thanks for the effort Evgeni